# Storing Files As Blob In MySQL Using Class Objects

Tags: .net, mysql, blob, autocad

I've got a table in my database that is to be used for storing AutoCad files. There is a field called Content of datatype Blob. I have a class object that matches the table in the database. What datatype should I use for the Content property of the class object? I'm not quite sure how I would store this into the database in code.

Comment: Are you specifically trying to target both C# and VB.Net?  If not, consider removing those tags and just adding .Net

Comment: the datatype property of hte class object for a blob field usualy is a byte array.

Comment: Ok that's what I currently have it as.